# Remove duplicates in Django ORM -- multiple rows

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model that has four fields. How do I remove duplicate objects from my database?

Daniel Roseman's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5877306/remove-duplicates-in-a-django-query) seems appropriate, but I'm not sure how to extend this to situation where there are four fields to compare per object.

Thanks,

W.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

```py
def remove_duplicated_records(model, fields):
    """
    Removes records from `model` duplicated on `fields`
    while leaving the most recent one (biggest `id`).
    """
    duplicates = model.objects.values(*fields)

    # override any model specific ordering (for `.annotate()`)
    duplicates = duplicates.order_by()

    # group by same values of `fields`; count how many rows are the same
    duplicates = duplicates.annotate(
        max_id=models.Max("id"), count_id=models.Count("id")
    )

    # leave out only the ones which are actually duplicated
    duplicates = duplicates.filter(count_id__gt=1)

    for duplicate in duplicates:
        to_delete = model.objects.filter(**{x: duplicate[x] for x in fields})

        # leave out the latest duplicated record
        # you can use `Min` if you wish to leave out the first record
        to_delete = to_delete.exclude(id=duplicate["max_id"])

        to_delete.delete()
```

You shouldn't do it often. Use `unique_together` constraints on database instead.

This leaves the record with the biggest `id` in the DB. If you want to keep the original record (first one), modify the code a bit with `models.Min`. You can also use completely different field, like creation date or something.

**Underlying  SQL**

When annotating django ORM uses `GROUP BY` statement on all model fields used in the query. Thus the use of `.values()` method. `GROUP BY` will group all records having those values identical. The duplicated ones (more than one `id` for `unique_fields`) are later filtered out in `HAVING` statement generated by `.filter()` on annotated `QuerySet`.

```sql
SELECT
    field_1,
    …
    field_n,
    MAX(id) as max_id,
    COUNT(id) as count_id
FROM
    app_mymodel
GROUP BY
    field_1,
    …
    field_n
HAVING
    count_id > 1
```

The duplicated records are later deleted in the `for` loop with an exception to the most frequent one for each group.

**Empty .order_by()**

Just to be sure, it's always wise to add an empty `.order_by()` call before aggregating a `QuerySet`.

The fields used for ordering the `QuerySet` are also included in `GROUP BY` statement. Empty `.order_by()` overrides columns declared in model's `Meta` and in result they're not included in the SQL query (e.g. default sorting by date can ruin the results).

You might not need to override it at the current moment, but someone might add default ordering later and therefore ruin your precious delete-duplicates code not even knowing that. Yes, I'm sure you have 100% test coverage…

Just add empty `.order_by()` to be safe. ;-)

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/aggregation/#interaction-with-default-ordering-or-order-by

**Transaction**

Of course you should consider doing it all in a single transaction.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic

Comment: Thanks! However, so that I can understand (I'm still very much a Django novice), could you please explain what is happening at each step?  I understand that `MyModel.objects.values(*unique_fields)` generates a set of dictionaries, with each dictionary pertaining to an object. But then I get lost - what is the annotate doing?

Comment: Brilliant! Works perfectly! It took me quite a bit of research and thinking to figure out exactly **how** it works (your explanation helped quite a bit and helped me figure out what I had to read...) but work it does! Thanks again (and apologies for the delay in getting back to this)

Comment: why excluding max ones? I would annotate on Min and exclude min, since they are the original ones. At the end it will still remove the dups, just keep the smallest id rather than the higher one.

Comment: @AndreMiras depends on the use case. Sometimes the last ones have the most up-to-date information.

Comment: I had an exception trying to run the code above: `NameError: name 'duplicate' is not defined` (Python3.4, Django1.11). This is what did work for me: `Role.objects.filter(**{field_1: d[field_1], ..., field_n: d[field_n]}).exclude(id=d['max_id']).delete()`. For some reason it didn't want to unzip it from the duplicate variable in the filter statement :/

Comment: @AnaPana didn't you write `for d in …` instead of `for duplicate in …`?

Comment: Oh, my bad. Yes, it should be `duplicate` instead of `d`. I tried to rename it to check that I do everything right. It still throws the exception in the first part of the queryset.

Answer (score 1):

### **If you want to delete duplicates on single or multiple columns, you don't need to iterate over millions of records.**

1. Fetch all unique columns (don't forget to include the primary key column)

   ```
   fetch = Model.objects.all().values("id", "skuid", "review", "date_time")
   ```
2. Read the result using pandas (I did using pandas instead ORM query)

   ```
   import pandas as pd
   df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(fetch)
   ```
3. Drop duplicates on unique columns

   ```
   uniq_df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=["skuid", "review", "date_time"])
   ## Dont add primary key in subset you dumb
   ```
4. Now, you'll get the unique records from where you can pick the primary key

   ```
   primary_keys = uniq_df["id"].tolist()
   ```
5. Finally, it's show time (exclude those id's from records and delete rest of the data)

   ```
   records = Model.objects.all().exclude(pk__in=primary_keys).delete()
   ```