# South migration - How to handle inconsistent data when adding a unique constraint

Tags: django, django-models, django-south

I have a model which looks like this:

```
class CollectionResource(models.Model):
    resource = models.ForeignKey(Resource)
    collection = models.ForeignKey(Collection)
    order = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

And I want to make sure that each collection will have a unique order value so I added:

```
class Meta:
    unique_together = ('collection', 'order')

manage.py schemamigration --auto my_app
manage.py migrate my_app
```

But I get an Integrity error since the values in my database are not according to the new constraints 
(I already have collections which have the same value for orde multiple times)

I know south won't make some voodoo magic and fix my data :) but I don't know how to fix those values. Should I write a raw SQL for this job ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please see my related answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13700200/django-remove-duplicate-objects-where-there-is-more-than-one-field-to-compare/13700642#1370064

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at South's [data migrations](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part3.html#data-migrations). You'll have to write a method that converts the data to your specifications (and ideally a reverse method for rolling back changes, though for something like this task it's not always possible).