# Django get the most recent object matching a query

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-queryset

Let's say I have a model of the sort of:

```
class Related(models.Model):
    ... stuff ....

class Example(models.Model):
    field1 = models.ForeignKey(Related, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='+')
    field2 = models.ForeignKey(Related, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='+')
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    ... more fields
```

What I want to do is select the latest example for each fixed pair of field1 and field2. I want to select **all** the fields from Example. Assume that the number of entries in Example could be in the order of millions.

An example sql query that would do the job is something like (assuming an app name 'test'):

```
select * from test_example as e 
where not exists (
    select id 
    from test_example as e2 
    where e2.field1_id = e.field1_id 
        and e2.field2_id = e.field2_id 
        and e2.created > e.created)
```

Is there any way that I express something similar with the QuerySet API? So far the only solution I have found is to run raw SQL and I would really like to avoid that.

Answer (score 2):

```
latest = Example.objects.filter(field1="foo", field2="bar").latest('created')
```

More here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#latest

Edit: The following answer is most likely what you're after:

[Django - remove duplicate objects where there is more than one field to compare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13700200/django-remove-duplicate-objects-where-there-is-more-than-one-field-to-compare)

Comment: I want my query to return the latest record for all pairs, not for a fixed pair `foo`, `bar`

Comment: So do you mean finding the latest of two "duplicate" records?

Comment: They are duplicate in a sense these two specific fields match for them, but they have many other fields

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I found works only for postresql, but luckily for me I am using postgresql.

First let us start with an explanation on a special clause that exists in postgresql - `DISTINCT ON`. You can read an example for using it [here](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/4-Using-Distinct-ON-to-return-newest-order-for-each-customer.html). In short it turns out a valid query in postgresql for my case would be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (e.field1_id, e.field2_id) e.* 
       FROM Example as e 
       ORDER BY e.created DESC
```

The essence in the above is that fact that I may use only a subset of the selected fields to compute DISTINCT on.

What is even better it turns out the django's QuerySet also supports that in [distinct](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct). More specifically(quote from the link):

> On PostgreSQL only, you can pass positional arguments (*fields) in
>   order to specify the names of fields to which the DISTINCT should
>   apply. This translates to a SELECT DISTINCT ON SQL query.

Using this I can write the following in django:

```
Example.objects.all().order_by('field1', 'field2', '-created').distinct(
        'field1', 'field2)
```

It is important to note that the distinct fields should be the first listed in the order_by clause and they should be in the same order.

I hope this answer will help someone else resolve similar issue.