# Django view queryset - how to remove duplicate queries

Tags: django, django-queryset

This is my **view** I filter the table by user, the model as a ForeignKey to another table.

```
class LaListaView(ListView):
    def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
        qs = super(OraListView, self).get_queryset()
        qs= qs.filter(Q(cod_operatore=self.request.user.username) ).prefetch_related()
        qs= qs.select_related()
        return qs
```

from django debug toolbar I get:

> SELECT ••• FROM "mat_app_materiale" WHERE
>   "mat_app_materiale"."rapp_rif_id" = 282 LIMIT 1 Duplicated 50 times.

The Duplicated  50 times action can be removed ? If yes how?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5877306/remove-duplicates-in-a-django-query

Comment: Please show your models, and the part of the template where you loop through the queryset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surely you don't want `prefetch_related()` as it does nothing without args.

You want `prefetch_related('parent_field_name')`.