# How to delete rows with duplicate columns in django

Tags: mysql, django

I have a model

```
class Foo(models.Model): 
     first = models.CharField()
     second = models.CharField()
```

data I have is

```
first second
1     2
1     2
1     2
3     4
```

Now I want to delete all duplicate rows and keep one entry. The end result

```
first second
1     2
3     4
```

How do I do this? I checked this question but could not figure it out properly. [Annotate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8989221/django-select-only-rows-with-duplicate-field-values)

I have tried

```
foo_ids = Foo.objects.annotate(first_c=Count('first'), second_c=Count('second')).filter(first_c__gt=1, second_c__gt=1).values('first', 'second', 'id')
```

Then try and figure out how to not delete one of each I list of duplicates.

Comment: Here's a great post answering your question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5879542/8326247

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing this.

```
from django.db.models import Count
duplicate_foo = Foo.objects.values('req_group','child_program__id').annotate(id_c=Count('id')).filter(id_c__gt=1)
for dups in duplicate_foo:
    for i, val in enumerate(Foo.objects.filter(first=dups['first'],                                                      
                                               second=dups['second'])):
        if i ==0:
            continue
        val.delete()
```

Not the most optimzed solution. But it works.

Comment: Speed depends on how many duplicates you have. If most of your records are not duplicated, this is faster than Exprator's answer.

Comment: Calling delete() on every single duplicate still triggers one DB query for each duplicate. That's a massive overhead if you deal with thousands of duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

It's an older thread, but both answers don't fit the bill for large datasets and lead to a huge number of queries.

You can use this generic method instead:

```
from django.apps import apps
from django.db.models import Count, Max


def get_duplicates_from_fields(app, model, fields, delete=False, **filters):
    """
    Returns duplicate records based on a list of fields,
    optionally deletes duplicate records.
    """
    Model = apps.get_model(app, model)
    duplicates = (Model.objects.filter(**filters).values(*fields)
                  .order_by()
                  .annotate(_max_id=Max('id'), _count=Count('id'))
                  .filter(_count__gt=1))

    for duplicate in duplicates:
        if delete:
            (
                Model.objects
                .filter(**filters)
                .filter(**{x: duplicate[x] for x in fields})
                .exclude(id=duplicate['_max_id'])
                .delete()
            )
        else:
            print(duplicate)
```

You can use this method as such:

```
get_duplicates_from_fields('myapp', 'Foo', ['first', 'second'], True)
```

This lets you find and delete duplicate records based on any number of fields.