# How do I remove duplicate records in an existing database? (no unique constraint defined)

Tags: python, django, database, django-models

I'm working on a project where improvements to database schema, query speed, and template inheritance are required. As an example, there is a *Menu* model that lacks a unique constraint (See below).

To improve the model's data integrity, I'm planning to add a migration by adding a `unique=True` constraint to the `season` field.

Before applying the migration, I checked the database for all *Menu* instances to see if an integrity error could potentially occur.  As a result of checking, there are 3 model instances with the same value assigned to `season`.

I want to remove all but 1 of the *Menu* instances from the existing database in this case, and it doesn't matter which one is kept. What would be some approaches to accomplishing this?

```
class Menu(models.Model):
    season = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    items = models.ManyToManyField('Item', related_name='items')
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(
            default=timezone.now)
    expiration_date = models.DateTimeField(
            blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.season
```

Comment: 1) [Remove duplicates in a django query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5877306/remove-duplicates-in-a-django-query) 2) [Remove duplicates in Django ORM — multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13700200/remove-duplicates-in-django-orm-multiple-rows/) Any of these help?

Answer (score 1):

You can below code if you are using Postgresql:

```py
all_unique_season = Menu.objects.distinct('season').values_list('id', flat=True)
Menu.objects.exclude(id__in=all_unique_season).delete()
```

Also if you are using other databases, you can use below code:

```py
used_ids = list()
for i in Menu.objects.values('id', 'season'):
    used_ids.append(i['id'])
    Menu.objects.filter(season=i['season']).exclude(id__in=used_ids).delete()
```

Comment: Wouldn't this delete all the model instances in example #2? If the model instances ids were `id=1`, `id=2`, and `id=3`, the first iteration would delete the instances with `id=2` and `id=3` because `id=i['id']` equals 1.

Upon the second iteration wouldn't the model instance with `id=1` be deleted because it's the only remaining model instance and `id=i['id']` would be 2?